# Change color using useState on React using Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, use-state

I like to change the color of the icon using `useState` by clicking on the icon, I added a click handler on the icon.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ThumbUpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUp';

function App() {

  const[likeColor, setLikeColor] = useState('');

  const colorStyle = {color:"blue"}

  const handleClick = () => {
      const color = likeColor ? '' : colorStyle;
      setLikeColor(color);
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThumbUpIcon onClick={handleClick} style={{likeColor}}></ThumbUpIcon>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The issue is that you are passing a string to style, but style takes an object `style={{likeColor}}`.  Try hard-coding color values there to make sure it works.  You probably want `style={{color: likeColor}}`

Answer (score 0):

You have an object inside of an object, I would try as:

```
<ThumbUpIcon onClick={handleClick} style={likeColor}></ThumbUpIcon>
```

See the difference in `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue "prop style must be object (css concept), so it should `style={likeColor}`". By the way, you should init value likeColor is a object instead empty string. So, i recommend you should change way like color work.

function App() {

```
const[isLike, setIsLike] = useState(false);

const colorStyle = {color:"blue"}

const handleClick = () => {
    setIsLike(!isLike);
}

return (
    <div className="App">
        <ThumbUpIcon onClick={handleClick} style={isLike ? colorStyle : null}></ThumbUpIcon>
    </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Please don't forget to vote and accepted my answer :)))